# How to prevent public key tampering

Tags: encryption, public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature, tpm, drm

I have to store a document (e.g. a JSON file) on a remote PC (that my App is running on) alongside a signature to be able to verify that this file was signed by me. I have no access to this PC nor does this PC have access to the internet. The user using the remote PC has root access.

I was thinking about storing this public key in a TPM (which the remote PC has) and setting policies that the key can be used only when my app is running and using some password stored in the app.

If I do this, would user be able to change this public key in the TPM, when he would match the system state? Thereby also change the stored signature and JSON file?

If yes, what are some best practices to keep the signature and key secure on an offline PC?

The most valuable information in the file is the date when my app should stop running. I need to make sure that the user cannot rewrite the date.

Comment: What do you mean "and some password stored in app"? You can't protect a password that's in the app against the user, except by hiding it and hoping nobody cares enough to look. Also, I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do (some kind of offline DRM scheme?), but trying to control what a user with physical and root access can do on a machine is folly, and when it's an _offline_ machine so you can't even use online-only DRM schemes... yeah, this isn't going to work. Even if you somehow prevent the user from changing the public key, they can just alter the app's signature check directly!

Comment: Yeah I know that user can also find the password, it's just another security layer he has to pass. My problem is that my App heavily depends on the *.json file and I need this file to be immutable. Or atleast I need to be sure that it's the same file I onced delivered with my app. Most valueble information in file is date when my app should stop running. I need to make sure that user just can not rewrite the date.

Comment: ... you realize that the user can just edit the system clock, right? If the system is offline there's not even any real reason not to do so. Or they can modify your software to remove the check or spoof the result (make the check think it's always one year before the app expires), as an alternative to removing the signature validation check.

Comment: I think you need to rethink the entire approach. You want to design a method where a root user on an offline PC can't use an application installed on the machine. Many large corporations tried to design such schemes. They all failed to do it perfectly. Every scheme was an annoyance to users who wanted to use the application legitimately.

Comment: Fortunately user can't edit clock because his work also heavily depends on it. 
But okay, let's say that I take away root access from user and now I am sole holder of the root access. I think I can manage to put this in contract. But how would you transform my approach with this changes? How hard is to break root access?

Comment: The user can install linux on a USB stick and boot the USB stick and now the user is root.

Comment: I can disable boot from usb in BIOS.